# Backups on tape HP Ultrium 460

Tags: debian, tape

There's subj tape drive (LTO-2 tapes, SCSI connection) connected to Debian 8. And I can't understand if it can make "session" writes? And, if yes, how correctly it has to be done?

I mean, that I need to write `somedir1` on tape once, then, after time, write `somedir2` on same tape and tape device have to "append" `somedir2` to already written data on tape. Something like multisessions writes on CD/DVD.

'Cause now I can't find a way to create any "sessions".

How I am writing:

`mt -f /dev/st0 eod` - setting tape to the end of data

`tar -czf /dev/st0 /somedir1` - writing `somedir1`

`mt -f /dev/st0 eod` - setting tape to the end of data again (cause tape device rewinds tape)

`tar -czf /dev/st0 /somedir2` - writing `somedir2`

`mt -f /dev/st0 rewind` - rewinding tape.

Then, when reading data with `tar -tzf /dev/st0` it only lists `somedir2`, but not `somedir1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `/dev/nst0`; `/dev/st0` rewinds when the device is closed, `/dev/nst0` doesn't. With your current workflow, you're always writing to the beginning of the tape...

You might also want to look into tape markers (see the `mt` documentation).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try using `/dev/nst0`

Answer (score 3):

Some notes about tape backup. Maybe somebody finds it useful...

1. Do not rewind tape after writing - use `/dev/nst0` device (in case of linux)
2. Set shell variable `TAPE=/dev/nst0`
3. Set head to the beginnig of tape: `mt rewind`
4. Set head to the end of written on tape data blocks: `mt eod`
5. Get current tape postion: `mt status` and see `File number` and `block number` values
6. Set tape head to the beginnig of previous block: `mt bsf 2; mt fsf`. Do not use to set head to the tape beginning - use rewind
7. `tar czv <dir_or_file>` - write `<dir_or_file>` to tape
8. `tar tzv` - get content of current block of data on tape (filelist).
9. Sometimes errors occurs - use `mt retension` to reset soft errors

Some quick bash-script with basic tape operations:

```
#!/bin/bash

export TAPE="/dev/nst0"
############################################
function anykey {
      read -n 1 -p "Press any key to continue..."
}

while true; do
clear
cat <<EOF
Choose action:

1. Show tape status
2. Show list of files of current block
3. Write new data (append tape)
4. Rewind tape (Set to BOT)
5. Wind tape (Set to EOD)
6. Set head to N blocks before
7. Set head to N blocks after
8. Extract data from current block
9. Erase tape

0. Exit
-----

EOF
read -p "Select action: " ans

case $ans in
    1).
      echo "====="; mt status ; echo "====="; anykey ;;
    2)
      echo "====="; tar tzv; echo "====="
      echo "Rewinding to the beginning of current block..."
      mt bsf 2; mt fsf
      echo "Done"; anykey ;;
    3).
      read -p "Select file or directory: " path
      cd $(dirname $path)
      if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
          anykey
          continue
      fi..
      echo "Positioning to the end of written data..."
      mt eod; tar czv $(basename $path) -C $(dirname $path)
      echo "Done"; anykey ;;
    4).
      echo "Rewinding tape..."; mt rewind; echo "Done"; anykey ;;
    5).
      echo "Winding tape..."; mt eod; echo "Done"; anykey ;;
    6)
      read -p "Enter number of blocks before to set to: " ans
      mt bsf $(($ans+1)); mt fsf
      echo "Done"; anykey ;;
    7)
      read -p "Enter number of blocks after to set to: " ans
      mt fsf $ans; echo "Done"; anykey ;;
    8)
      read -p "Enter folder where to extract: " path
      cd $path
      if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
          anykey
          continue
      fi
      read -p "Extract all data from this block? [Y|n]: " ans
      if [ $ans == "n" ]; then
          read -p "Enter file or dir name: " ans
          tar zxpv $ans
      else
          tar zxpv
      fi
      echo "Done"; anykey ;;
    9)
      echo "WARNING! Erasing will destroy ALL data on tape! Continue? [y|n]"; read ans
      if [ $ans == "y" ]; then
          echo "Rewinding tape..."; mt rewind;.
          echo "Erasing tape. This is quite long operation..."; mt erase; echo "Done"
      fi
      anykey ;;
    0) exit 0 ;;
    *) continue ;;
esac
done
```

[Tape drive devices](http://etutorials.org/Linux+systems/how+linux+works/Chapter+13+Backups/13.6+Tape+Drive+Devices/)